# How to make the useRef hooks work in this code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a project about a beer wishlist in which I used React. The problem is I get this error

```
TS2786: 'EditBeerPage' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.
    32 |                     <Route path='/' element={<DisplayBeersPage />} />
    33 |                     <Route path='/addBeer' element={<AddbeerPage />} />
  > 34 |                     <Route path='/editBeer' element={<EditBeerPage />} />
       |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    35 |                 </Routes>
    36 |             </BrowserRouter>
    37 |         </BeersContextProvider>
```

and I don't know how to fix this. I can provide more detail about my code if it is needed.

```
import { BeersContext } from '../../contexts/BeersContext';
import { BeerForm } from '../../features/CRUD operations/Beer form/BeerForm';
import { Layout } from '../../shared/components/layout/layout';
import { Button } from '../../shared/components/button/button';
import { Beer } from '../../models/Beer';
import React from 'react';
import { useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function handleOnClick(
    idInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>,
    nameInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>,
    manufacturerInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>,
    typeInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>,
    urlInput: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>,
) {
    if (!idInput.current || !nameInput.current || !manufacturerInput.current || !typeInput.current || !urlInput.current)
        throw new Error('Inputs references are null');

    if (!idInput.current.value || !nameInput.current.value || !manufacturerInput.current.value || !typeInput.current.value || !urlInput.current.value)
        throw new Error('You must provide values for each field!');

    const beerId: number = parseInt(idInput.current.value),
        beerName: string = nameInput.current.value,
        beerManufacturer: string = manufacturerInput.current.value,
        beerType: string = typeInput.current.value,
        beerUrl: string = urlInput.current.value;

    return new Beer(beerId, beerName, beerManufacturer, beerType, beerUrl);
}

export function EditBeerPage() {
    document.title = 'Edit Beer';

    const idInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const nameInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const manufacturerInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const typeInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const urlInput = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const beersContext = useContext(BeersContext)!;

    const { beerId } = useParams();
    if (!beerId) {
        navigate('/');
        return;
    }

    const givenBeer = beersContext.beers.find((beer: Beer) => beer.getID() === parseInt(beerId));
    console.log('Given Beer:', givenBeer); // Log the value of givenBeer
    const handleOnClickWrapper = () => {
        try {
            const newBeer = handleOnClick(idInput, nameInput, manufacturerInput, typeInput, urlInput);
            beersContext.removeBeer(newBeer.getID());
            beersContext.addBeer(newBeer);

            navigate('/');
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className='main-page-container'>
                <BeerForm
                    idInput={idInput}
                    nameInput={nameInput}
                    manufacturerInput={manufacturerInput}
                    typeInput={typeInput}
                    urlInput={urlInput}
                    givenBeer={givenBeer}
                />

                <Button type='submit' buttonMessage='Edit Beer' onClick={handleOnClickWrapper} />
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

thats the code for the EditBeerPage part.

the project is correctly created using npm create-react-app lab1 --template typescript. I use Visual Studio Code.

Tried editing EditBeerPage part of the code and others, changing from undefined to null and other things, but none worked. I installed the latest versions of react-router and react-dom. ChatGPT confirmed EditBeerPage return valid JSX components

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvxXQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you, `<Route path='/editBeer' element={<EditBeerPage />} />` is expecting a `JSX.Element` or `null` for the `element` prop. Currently `EditBeerPage` is conditionally returning `undefined` when there is no `beerId`.

The problem is here:

```
    if (!beerId) {
        navigate('/');
        return;
    }
```

If you return `undefined`, TypeScript considers this a possibility and tells you about it before you run the code.

Try changing it to:

```
    if (!beerId) {
        navigate('/');
        return null;
    }
```

As for the second issue you are having with the `useRef` being null, I believe the problem is here:

```
if (!idInput.current.value || !nameInput.current.value || !manufacturerInput.current.value || !typeInput.current.value || !urlInput.current.value)
        throw new Error('You must provide values for each field!');
```

You should add optional chaining to check for null values:

```
    if (!idInput.current?.value || !nameInput.current?.value || !manufacturerInput.current?.value || !typeInput.current?.value || !urlInput.current?.value)
        throw new Error('You must provide values for each field!');
```

Comment: see above the outcome

Answer (score 0):

[i noticed this in the inspect element when i checked the browser to pause on caught exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LBRv.png)

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

import React from 'react';

import { BeersContextType, ProviderType } from '../types/BeersContextTypes.types';

export const BeersContext = createContext<BeersContextType | null>(null);

export function BeersContextProvider({ beerContext, children }: ProviderType) {
    return <BeersContext.Provider value={beerContext}>{children}</BeersContext.Provider>;
}
```

thats the code for BeersContext